# Fetch GET request unhandled rejection

Tags: javascript, json, get, backend, crud

I'm doing a basic request to a backend in JS (only to check a user instance exists and will return a bool (true/false) to prevent returning full user data until needed)

From what I have been told by peers it's ill-advised to be passing sensitive data (in this case people's emails) via paths and should be via the body (I haven't looked into why) Anyway, so the way I configured it was to be contained within the body like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/User/check
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "email" : "B.Nye@ABC.uk"
}
```

However when doing this call in JS:

```
  if (isAuthenticated){
    console.log("test -----------")
    console.log(user.email)
    fetch("http://###.###.###.###:8080/User/check", {
       method: "GET", 
       headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
       body: JSON.stringify( {
          email: "B.Nye@ABC.uk"
       })
       
  }).then((result)=> {
    if (result.ok){
      console.log("sucess")
    }
    else{
      console.log("fail")
  }})}
```

I get this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Is there a way to bypass this or am I restricted to using either a POST method and reworking my backend method or containing the users email inside of the path?

Comment: Why are you not using query string parameters if you are using a GET?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: @epascarello Because he's been told it's "ill-advised" :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you want to use body, you should use POST method. This is why the Fetch API keeps sending errors to you.

The second question is, why do we not use GET method while we are sending sensitive datas like emails, passwords etc. The answer is, entire URL is cached user's browser history and it may expose user's sensitive data. And it will be much more secure if you use POST method because it prevents data leakage via the query string (you are sending data in the body).

Comment: If an attacker captures the request, it won't matter if it is GET or POST and if it is SSL encrypted, query string will be encrypted too

Comment: You are right but I think if we use GET method to pass that sensitive stuff we made it easy for the attacker, but at the end if the attacker captures the request it won't matter as you've said.